# Do external EMFs affect in some way a capacitor?

Tags: emf

I Know that inducters are affected by external magnetic fields .The affect depends on the construction of the inducter  . What I would like to know is how capacitors are affected by external electrostatic fields ?   Mutual inductance is well covered elsewhere but what about mutual capacitance?

Comment: Are you looking for EMF (electromotive force, i.e. voltage), or are you looking for EMI (electromagnetic interference)? Your question seems to ask about one and then completely turn around and talk about the other.

Comment: I'm looking for EMF.

Comment: To be honest, mutual capacitance isn't normally covered for a few reasons. Firstly, the object would have to be between the positive and negative charges to really "couple" into the field. Metals are practically unaffected while in a field. Charge migration within a metal means that the charges just rearrange to let the field pass perpendicular to the surface (not through it). There are instances where mutual capacitance happens, we just call it "parasitic capacitance." This happens because any conductor carrying a charge/current can effect all other signal conductors via (ε*A)/d.

Answer (score 1):

capacitors constructed with of non-linear dielectrics could in theory be effected by external fields, but in a typical capacitor the thickness is much less than the width, so this effect would only be around the perimeter of the dielectric, so while present it's probably not measurable.